# What sets are these electrical parts from, dark grey bases and remotes with orange and yellow buttons?

Tags: technic, power-functions, electronics

I have been searching for a long time but I am struggling to find the origin for these parts. I think they are possibly Power Functions IR remotes & battery packs...?

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Battery Boxes on the left are [5115](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5115-1) or [9831](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9831-1) (most likely the former) from the 9V system ([immediate predecessor of Power Functions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/powerfunctions/faqs)). These don't come from sets but were items that were available for purchase on their own.

The middle unit is [23323c01 Electric, Bionicle Motor Remote Control Receiver Unit, Complete Assembly (Manas)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23323c01#T=C&C=10) from set [8539 Manas](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8539-1) from the Bionicle theme from 2001.

[image]

Finally, the two remote controllers on the right are item [23335c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23335c01#T=C&C=10) also from 8539 Manas.